# do we need to disable swap for riak?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, swap, ram, riak

I just found in the riak documentation that the swap makes the server unresponsive so it has to be disabled.It is also given that  Riak node be allowed to be killed by the kernel if it uses too much RAM. If swap is completely disabled, Riak will simply exit. I am confused should we have to disable the swap or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/cookbooks/Linux-Performance-Tuning/

> Swap Space
>
> Due to the heavily I/O-focused profile of Riak, swap usage
>   can result in the entire server becoming unresponsive. Disable swap or
>   otherwise implement a solution for ensuring Riak's process pages are
>   not swapped.
>
> Basho recommends that the Riak node be allowed to be killed by the
>   kernel if it uses too much RAM. If swap is completely disabled, Riak
>   will simply exit when it is unable to allocate more RAM and leave a
>   crash dump (named erl_crash.dump) in the /var/log/riak directory which
>   can be used for forensics (by Basho Client Services Engineers if you
>   are a customer).

So no, you don't *have* to ... but if you don't and you use all your available RAM the machine is likely to become unresponsive.

With *any* (unbounded) application that performs heavy I/O where you could exhaust your system's memory that's going to be the case. Typically you would have monitoring on the machine that warned you of memory usage going past a threshold.